# Process 'command 'C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

I am not able to upgrade my android P project to android Q, aidl files are not compiling, and apk generation fails with the error

Tried dummy android Q project, that compiled successfully. But even there when I added aidl file saw the same error.

> Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\snehan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\aidl.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819
>
> compiler changes: compileSdkVersion 29 buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
>   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip